# I am getting an error message saying that the static field "CELL_TYPE_***" should be accessed in a static way

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am getting an error message when I hover over the 'CELL_TYPE_****' methods in the method getCellData(), saying that 'the static field "CELL_TYPE_***" should be accessed in a static way' and a strike line over them.

```js
        package excelSelenium;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class seleniumIntg {
 XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
 XSSFSheet sheet = null;
 XSSFRow Row = null;
 XSSFCell Cell = null;
 WebDriver driver = null;
 
 

 @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
 public void doLogin(String username, String password)
 {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://testing/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe" );
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
 
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fpctx&.intl=in&.lang=en-IN&.done=https://in.yahoo.com/%3fp=us");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-username']")).sendKeys(username);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mbr-login-submit']/button")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-passwd']")).sendKeys(password);
  
 }
 @DataProvider
 public Object[][] getData() throws IOException
 {
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C://Users/Gaurav/Documents/testid.xlsx");
  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  sheet = workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
  int rowCount = sheet.getFirstRowNum()+sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
  int colCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
  System.out.println("Row count is:" +rowCount+ "Col count is:" +colCount);
  Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount-1][colCount];
  for(int rNum = 2; rNum<=rowCount; rNum++)
   for(int cNum = 0; cNum<colCount; cNum++)
   {
    System.out.println(getCellData("sheet1",cNum,rNum));
    data[rNum-2][cNum]=getCellData("sheet1",cNum,rNum);
    
   }
  return data; 
  
 }
 
 
 public String getCellData(String sheetName, int colNum, int rowNum)
 {
  try{
  if(rowNum<=0)
   return "";
  int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
  if(index == -1)
   return "";
  sheet =workbook.getSheetAt(index);
  Row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
  if(Row==null)
   return "";
  Cell = Row.getCell(colNum);
  if(Cell==null)
   return "";
  else if(Cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
   return Cell.getStringCellValue();
  
  else if(Cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC||Cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)
   {String CellText = String.valueOf(Cell.getNumericCellValue());
  return CellText;}
  else if(Cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
   return "";
  else return String.valueOf(Cell.getBooleanCellValue());
 }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return "row"+rowNum+"col"+colNum+"Does not exist";
  }
  
   
  
  
 }
 
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In instructions such as :

```
else if(Cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
```

despite appearances, `Cell` is an instance and not a class as you declare this field in your class:

```
XSSFCell Cell = null;
```

But static fields and methods have no need to be prefixed by an instance to call them but by the class.

So you should prefix the static fields you are referencing like that :

```
else if(Cell.getCellType()==XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
```

To avoid this kind of misleading code that gives the impression that you are using as prefix an instance while you are using actually a class, follow the Java code conventions that say among other things that variable names should start by a lowercase character.

This is better :

```
XSSFCell cell = null;
...
else if(cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
```

As a side note, [the `CELL_TYPE_STRING` static field is deprecated](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#CELL_TYPE_STRING) since POI 3.15 beta 3.
You are advised to use the enum `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.STRING` instead of.

Comment: Hi David! Thanks a lot for the help, but I am still getting the same error. 'The field CELL_TYPE_STRING is deprecated'.

Comment: Hello Gaurav. It is not a compilation error but "only" a warning. I have just updated my answer to address it .

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you should rename your variables, so that they start with lower-case letters (e.g. `cell` instead of `Cell`) to avoid confusion.

So `cell` is an instance of class [XSSFCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html) which inherits from `Cell`.

The static fields e.g. [CELL_TYPE_STRING](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#CELL_TYPE_STRING) are declared in the class [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) 
: so you should use `Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING` instead of `cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING`